# Android - CordovaWebView cannt load html file from assets

Tags: android, cordova, webview, cordovawebview

I'm using **CordovaWebView** in my android project.
When I run application app load catch and show a blank toast message.
and inside logcat i see an error that say file not exists in assets.
I added **jar** file to **libraries** and added **CordovaWebView** inside my activity layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="11"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView
        android:id="@+id/tutorialView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and used this code for loading **html** file from **assets** :

```
CordovaWebView cwv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_course);

    try{
        cwv = (CordovaWebView) findViewById(R.id.tutorialView);
        cwv.loadUrlIntoView("file:///android_asset/test.html");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        ToastHelper.Long(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

html file exists in assets and I can load it using **WebView** (not **CordovaWebView**).

Please share with me your ideas to solving this problem.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use

```
cwv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");
```

instead of

```
cwv.loadUrlIntoView("file:///android_asset/test.html");
```

see this

https://web.archive.org/web/20140514125044/http://www.infil00p.org/advanced-tutorial-using-cordovawebview-on-android/

Comment: the link helped me fix problem. thank you, but html cant load fonts, in fact I use cordovaWebView instead of WebView because webview cant load Persian and Arabic font , I saw some Persian applications that load fonts by using CordovaWebView, any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2):

for index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

  <head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no" />

    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <title>PhoneGap Android App</title>

              <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>      


 <style type="text/css">
@font-face {
    font-family: AayatQuraan;
    src: url("file:///android_asset/fonts/AayatQuraan.ttf")
}
body {
    font-family: AayatQuraan;
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: justify;
}
</style>
  </head>

  <body onload="init();"  >
جميل
  </body>

</html>
```

for java

```
package com.example.hellogap;


import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);        
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html",1000);
    }

}
```

output something like this=

[image]

Comment: is this font different from device default font ?